# Restart CoreAnimation after view appears

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-animation

I have a custom view with additional layers and a simple endless animation (using core animation). The view is a subclass of UITableViewCell and therefore doesn't have it's own view controller.

The animation gets stopped whenever the view disappears, which is fine. But how do I restart the animation when the view reappears?

Comment: Have you tried starting the animation when you configure the cell in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: ?

Comment: That function doesn't get called when the view reappears...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way of doing it. This might not be the best solution, but at least it's very simple. Just add this in the corresponding `UITableViewController`:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```